# Check if the array has three consecutive numbers in sequence

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

i have an array like below

`[1,2,'b',4 ,'a','b',5,'o',7,1,3,'p',9,'p']`

I want to check that if the above array has three consecutive numbers in a sequence (i.e) `[1,2,3]`.

From the above array i want the output as below given example

`[7,1,3]` - > Since this sequence is occuring in a sequence without getting blocked by a alphabet.

Comment: OK, so you'll need to loop through the array, look ahead to the next two items (where available), test the types of all three items, and then slice out the result if they're all numbers. Which bits do you need help with?

Comment: Try to ask queries regarding the problem, not the entire problem here.

Comment: @Rup, yes exactly, i tried with few function, tht works with full of numbers in array, above example has combinaion of numbers with strings, so as i want to differentiate them and find only the three consecutive occurances of number alone

Comment: do you have only one block, or could be more than one block of consecutive numbers in the data?

Comment: So your problem is differentiating a number from a string? You can use `typeof()`. Is that enough for you to solve this yourself now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do this . Just iterate over array and `count` number of occurance of numbers. As soon as count becomes 3 you have your magic numbers otherwise reset all. As @Rup suggested.

```js
var arr = [1,2,'b',4 ,'a','b',5,'o',7,1,3,'p',9,'p'];
var result = [];
var count = 0;
arr.forEach(function(element) {
   if(typeof (element) == "number" ){
    count +=1;
    result.push(element)
  }else {
    if(count == 3){
     console.log(result);
     return ;
    }else if(count < 3){
     count = 0;
     result= [];
    }
  }
 
});
```

Comment: works perfect @manikant

Comment: @AshwinS glad to hear !

Answer (score 1):

You could take a temporary array and fill it with found numbers. For any not found number, empty the array and check then the length. If it has the wanted length, push the array to the result set.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 'b', 4, 'a', 'b', 5, 'o', 7, 1, 3, 'p', 9, 'p'],
    three = array.reduce((temp => (r, v) => {
        if (typeof v !== 'number') {
            temp = [];
            return r;
        }
        temp.push(v);
        if (temp.length === 3) {
            r.push(temp);
        }
        return r;
    })([]), []);

console.log(three);
```

Comment: that helped Nina